# C#:Difference between executing a program directly and call by another process

Tags: c#, cmd, process, scheduled-tasks

I've written a program named "CopyFile" to copy a file from local to a network shared folder repeatedly as below:

```
List<string> log = new List<string>();
string originPath = "*LOCAL PATH*";
string targetPath = "*TARGET PATH*";

System.Diagnostics.Process p = new System.Diagnostics.Process();
p.StartInfo.FileName = "cmd.exe";
p.StartInfo.UseShellExecute = false;
p.StartInfo.RedirectStandardInput = true;
p.StartInfo.RedirectStandardOutput = true;
p.StartInfo.CreateNoWindow = true;

if (File.Exists(originPath))
{
  p.Start();
  StreamWriter sw = p.StandardInput;
  sw.WriteLine(@"NET USE *TARGET IP* *PASSWORD* /USER:*USERNAME*");
  sw.WriteLine(@"COPY "+'"'+originPath+'"'+ " "+'"'+targetPath+'"');
  sw.WriteLine("Y");
  sw.WriteLine("EXIT");
  sw.Close();                  
  p.WaitForExit();

  log.Add(p.StandardOutput.ReadToEnd());
}
else 
{                  
  log.Add("No file");   
}
```

I tried this program in my computer, if I execute this program by double clicking it the program executing successfully . But if I use another C# program or windows task scheduler to call and execute it. The program cannot work normal. I've checked the log file to see the output . The log of double click  and execute it shows:

```
D:\Downtime>NET USE *TARGET IP* *PASSWORD* /USER:*USERNAME*
The command complete successfully.
D:\Downtime>COPY *originpath* *targetpath*
1 file(s) copied.
D:\Downtime>EXIT
```

But if I use another C# program or windows task scheduler to execute it, the log shows

```
C:\Windows\system32>NET USE *TARGET IP* *PASSWORD* /USER:*USERNAME*

C:\Windows\system32>COPY *originpath* *targetpath*
0 file(s) copied.

C:\Windows\system32>EXIT
```

Looks like if I call it by another program or the windows task scheduler the "cmd.exe" will not execute the command "NET USE" so I cannot connect to network computer and copy files to it.
Does anyone know what is the problem ? Thanks.

Comment: Drives are mapped by user token. Admins have two AsAdmin and Limited. However you don't need to do any of this. `copy  "\\servername\sharename\folder\file.ext" "\\servername\sharename\folder\file.ext"`. Mapping drives is a compatibility thing for pre windows 95 programs that people didn't stop using.

Comment: Quite likely the error message that's being generated by the `NET USE` command is being written to `StandardError`. You'll have to capture that output, too, if you want to see what it's saying.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know you path is absolute path or relative path. If you using relative path in your code, you should consider to set WorkingDirectory property of ProcessStartInfo instance.

When you call your program directly. WorkingDirectory is the directory contain executable file.

When you call your program from other process, working directory is the directory of other process - not your program.

So in this case, you must set WorkingDirectory property correctly.

Read more at [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.processstartinfo.workingdirectory(v=vs.110).aspx).

Comment: Thanks,I add WorkingDirectory to my program and it works.